# What are the differences of Flux<T>, Flux<ResponseEntity<T>>, ResponseEntity<Flux<T>> as return type in Spring WebFlux?

Tags: spring, flux, webflux, response-entity

I often see three different response return types: `Flux<T>`, `ResponseEntity<Flux<T>>`, and `Flux<ResponseEntity<T>>` in MVC style controllers using Spring WebFlux.  The [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html) explains the difference between `ResponseEntity<Flux<T>>` and `Flux<ResponseEntity<T>>`.  Does Spring automatically wrap `Flux<T>` as either `ResponseEntity<Flux<T>>` or `Flux<ResponseEntity<T>>`?  if yes, which one?

Moreover, how to decide which one to return, `ResponseEntity<Flux<T>>` or `Flux<ResponseEntity<T>>`?  What situation or use case would call for using one over the other?

And, from a webclient's point of view, are there any significant differences when consuming the two types of response?

Answer (score 4):

> Does Spring automatically wrap Flux as either
> ResponseEntity<Flux> or Flux<ResponseEntity>? if yes, which one?

Spring will automatically wrap that Flux as a ResponseEntity<Flux>. For example if you have a web endpoint as follows

> @GetMapping("/something")
> public Flux handle() {
> doSomething()
> }

And if you are consuming from a WebClient, you can retrieve your response as either [`ResponseEntity<Flux<T>>`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.ResponseSpec.html#toEntity-java.lang.Class-) or [`Flux<T>`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec.html#exchangeToFlux-java.util.function.Function-). There is no default, but I would think it's good practice to retrieve only Flux unless you explicitly need something from the ResponseEntity. [The Spring doc has good examples of this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webflux#2-retrieving-a-collection-resource).

You actually can consume it as a `Flux<ResponseEntity<T>>`, but this would only be applicable for more complex use cases.

> Moreover, how to decide which one to return, ResponseEntity<Flux>
> or Flux<ResponseEntity>? What situation or use case would call for
> using one over the other?

It really depends on your use case.

Returning `ResponseEntity<Flux<T>>` is saying something like,

```
I am returning a Response of a Collection of type T objects.
```

Where `Flux<ResponseEntity<T>>` is saying something more like

```
I am returning a Collection of Responses, where the responses have an entity of type T.
```

Again, I think in most use cases returning just `Flux<T>` makes sense (This is equivalent to returning `ResponseEntity<Flux<T>>`)

And finally

> And, from a webclient's point of view, are there any significant
> differences when consuming the two types of response?

I think what you're trying to ask is whether you should be using `ResponseEntity<Flux<T>>` or `Mono<ResponseEntity<T>>` when consuming from the WebClient. [And the spring doc answers this question quite elegantly](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-ann-responseentity)

> ResponseEntity<Flux> make the response status and headers known
> immediately while the body is provided asynchronously at a later
> point.

> Mono<ResponseEntity> provides all three — response status, headers,
> and body, asynchronously at a later point. This allows the response
> status and headers to vary depending on the outcome of asynchronous
> request handling.

Comment: very clear explanations, thanks.  To clarify my question on webclient:  Is the webclient code for consuming `Flux<ResponseEntity<T>>` any different from those for consuming `ResponseEntity<Flux<T>>`?

Comment: Yes they will be different. As stated in the original answer:

`ResponseEntity<Flux> make the response status and headers known immediately while the body is provided asynchronously at a later point.`

`Mono<ResponseEntity> provides all three — response status, headers, and body, asynchronously at a later point....`

In other words, with ResponseEntity<Flux<T>> your response status and headers will be obtained synchronously by the ResponseEntity  object, where with Flux<ResponseEntity<T>> you will be provided a Flux that provides the response status, header, and body all at once.

Comment: I got this error when I'm using Flux<ResponseEntity<T>>

```java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Only a single ResponseEntity supported
 at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:121) ~[spring-core-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
 Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: ```

Comment: A flux returns multiple objects, where it looks like a function you are calling is expecting 'a single ResponseEntity'. What is the code snippet you are running?